# Selenium test schedule via Jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, schedule

I would like to schedule task which is login to a partner site and prolongs a license. I found that it can do Selenium. After I faced issue with scheduler and found article here http://www.learnseleniumtesting.com/ about Jenkins configuration. Now I cannot understand how to run test from selenium in Jenkins. Is there need good knowledge in python or java ? Also I found that RC standalone selenium server is deprecated and avoided to be using now. Is there need deep diving into using these tools for executing 5-7 action on site ?

Answer (score 0):

I feel that Selenium is great for doing any tasks that you may find yourself doing over and over again. For "prolonging a license" on a partner site I think this is the perfect tool for you. We setup Jenkins to run certain Selenium tests after each commit and other Selenium tests every night. If you need me to go into more detail about how the setup looks I would be glad to show you more details.

Adding Jenkins build information to help show how we did it.

1) The first step is to get a build in Jenkins that will compile any code you have and deploy a war if needed with something similar to the following: `mvn -P release clean test package`. We set ours to build @midnight shown in the picture below. 
[image]
2) After this build finishes it triggers the next job to run this command shown in the image below: `mvn -Dtest -P smokeTest clean verify`
[image]

Comment: Yes, please. It would be great

Comment: user2027175 - I updated the original answer with some Jenkins configs.